# Is there a way to get node-nlp to recognize dutch language?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nlp

Allright we are trying to make a chatbot, but we need it to recognize dutch language, this is the code we have so far, but we don't know how to add dutch language support. We already tried alot but we dont seem to get it working!

```
const builder = require('botbuilder');
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const { Recognizer,LangNl } = require('node-nlp');
const modelName = './smalltalk.nlp';
const excelName = './smalltalk.xls';

// Creates a connector for the chatbot
const connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: null,
    appPassword: null,
});

// Creates a node-nlp recognizer for the bot
const recognizer = new Recognizer();



if (fs.existsSync(modelName)) {
    recognizer.load(modelName);
} else {
    recognizer.loadExcel(excelName);
    recognizer.save(modelName);
}


// Creates the bot using a memory storage, with a main dialog that
// use the node-nlp recognizer to calculate the answer.
const bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, (session) => {
    recognizer.nlpManager.addLanguage("nl","Nl","NL")
    recognizer.recognize(session, (err, data) => {
        session.send(data.answer || 'I don\'t understand');
        session.endDialog();
    });
}).set('storage', new builder.MemoryBotStorage());

recognizer.setBot(bot, false);

// Creates the express application
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());
app.listen(port);
console.log(`Chatbot listening on port ${port}`);
```